# Using overlap with different layer file to create a simple Y/N field in attributes of another layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, overlapping-features, feature-layer

I have two layers, which I wish to use one of to educate and populate an attribute field in the other layer with a simple Yes/No for if they overlap in terms of location.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Union, then check the FID fields. Those with a -1 in the FID from the "other layer" do not overlap said layer; all others do overlap it. So use field calculator to populate Y or N in your desired field based on whether the relevant FID is -1.

Comment: @Tom I think you should write that up as an answer

Answer (score 1):

1. [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-union-analysis-works.htm) the two feature classes.
2. Check the resulting fields that start with 'FID_'; one of them should be something like 'FID_NameOfMyFeatureClass' (depending on the dataset type, this may be truncated). A value of -1 in that field indicates that that feature class did not overlap your other feature class.
3. So, you can [select records](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-attributes.htm) that have a -1 in that field
4. Then use [field calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/making-field-calculations-making-simple-field-calc.htm) to populate your desired Y/N field with 'N'.
5. [Invert](https://maybeitsamap.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/quick-tip-049/) the selection
6. Use field calculator to populate the Y/N field with 'Y'
7. Then you may also want to delete features that have a -1 in the 'FID_NameOfMyOtherFeatureClass' field. These are areas that were not covered by your other feature class.